# Omiting undefined computed property in JS object

Tags: javascript, computed-properties

This is the default behavior of computed properties in JS:

```
const yourName = 'John';

const resultObject = {
    [yourName]: 'Glad you're here, let's celebrate!'
}
```

The resultObject will be computed to this:

```
console.log(resultObject)

{
   John: 'Glad you\'re here, let\'s celebrate!'
}
```

**NOW...** what will happen if yourName is undefined?

```
const yourName = undefined;
const resultObject = {
    [yourName]: 'Glad you\'re here, let\'s celebrate!'
}

console.log(resultObject)

{
   undefined: 'Glad you\'re here, let\'s celebrate!'
}
```

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way to omit the undefined computed property in the resulting object?

In other words, I'd like resultObject to be:

```
console.log(resultObject)

{/** void */}
```

Comment: Maybe just `delete resultObject.undefined` :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Either add the property procedurally after  checking the value or use the spread property trick shown in the duplicates.